# A true value is returned to the caller , even with out specifying any return value in the return statement

Tags: java, return

```java
public class FlourPacker {
    public static boolean canPack(int bigCount, int smallCount, int goal) {
        if ((bigCount < 0 || smallCount < 0 || goal < 0))
            return false;
        if ((bigCount * 5) < goal)
            return ((goal - (bigCount * 5)) <= smallCount);
        else return ((goal % 5) <= smallCount);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(canPack(3, 0, 11));
    }
}
```

So in this problem `bigCount` is worth 5 and `smallCount` is worth 1 and I am supposed to try to get the goal number. I can not go over(the goal) with the `bigCount` but I can with a `smallCount`.

But my question is, how come in the last **`if`** and **`else`** statement I don't need to put `true` or `false` for the return? when I run it (ie. the main method that I created) it tells me `true` even though I never put `return true` in the code.

Comment: Return is not a method. It is a statement.

Comment: Side note, this is the correct solution to the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to specify `true` or `false` specifically. If you did, then all your if-statements would have to be `if (true)` or `if (false)`.

So, instead, you write an expression inside the if-statement that evaluates to `true` or `false` (Taking your example, `if ((bigCount * 5) < goal)` will be equivalent to into `if (true)` or `if (false)` after plugging in the values from the variables).

This same idea goes for return statements (`return ((goal % 5)<= smallCount)` will become `return true` or `return false`).

Answer (score 0):

> how come in the last if and else statement I don't need to put true or
>   false for the return?

The answer is because you *return the result of a comparison operation, using relational opertaors*. Always a comparison operation will return true or false (boolean values).

For eg : when the `(goal - (bigCount * 5)) <= smallCount);`  is evaluated its output will be always a boolean value (a true or a false!!!). The corresponding return statement will return it to the caller (here it is a print statement). It will be displayed on your console.

Ref : [Relational operators](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/java-relational-operators-with-examples/)